Document upload for documents other than images in grapesjs
I am building a website using grapesjs. I have successfully configured asset manager with my server media directory. Now I want to upload documents other than only images. like pdf, excel, docx etc. How to do that.
This is my code of asset manager
assetManager: { 
    upload: '/upload_assets/', // Your file upload endpoint 
    uploadText: 'Drop files here or click to upload', 
    uploadName: 'files', // The name used to post the files 
    multiUpload: true, // Allow multiple file uploads 
    autoAdd: true, // Automatically add uploaded assets to the asset manager 
    assets: [], // Initial assets (optional) 
    headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': getCookie("csrftoken")} 
},

